# How To pivot a table without the pivot function?

Tags: sql

I need to pivot a table, make the row values into columns but the catch is that I dont have pivot functionality to call. I need to find a workaround to get this done.

Example:

```
NAME   SUBJECT     MARKS
Adam    maths        88
Adam    Science      76
Matt    Science      87
joe     English      90 
joe     Maths        80 
joe     Science      40  

Needs to look like : 

NAME     SCIENCE   MATHS    ENGLISH   
Adam        76      88        null
Matt        87      null      null
Joe         40      80        90
```

and I dont have pivot function available.

Comment: What kind of sql database are you using?

Comment: And just as important: what have you tried so far?

Comment: SQL database is BigSQL, its an IBM SQL MPP engine for Hadoop distribution.

Comment: So far, I am working with left outer join found here 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21669899

But this resulted in a result which looks like 
`NAME     SCIENCE   MATHS    ENGLISH   
Adam        76                 null       null
Adam        null                88         null
Matt          87                  null       null
Joe           40                  null       null
Joe           null                 80        null
Joe           null                 null       90
`

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of pivot you can get the same results with case statements inside your aggregate function...

```
select
    name,
    science = sum(case when subject = 'science' then marks else null end)
    maths = sum(case when subject = 'maths' then marks else null end)
from
    table
group by
    name
```

Comment: note that in the case where the possible columns are not fixed, you will have to go a little farther than this. Also I believe this will print 0 for non-existent scores rather than null.

Comment: if columns aren't fixed you'd have to use dynamic sql and that is the same case for a pivot. null values updated, good catch.